# Issue with topbar CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my code to have two navigation on top of each other This is the code below that I have and my CSS. How do I do a division line after every link on the second nav? This is what I am trying to archive.

Is there a way to add icons to the navigation?

[image: what should be]

```css
navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #444444;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 90px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}
```

```html
<navbar>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <!-- float this left -->
    <li>Sunt</li>
    <li>Beatae Vita</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Doleremquee laudantium otam Doloremque laudantium otam</p>
  <ul class="nav-items">
    <!-- float this right-->
    <li>Arhieto</li>
    <li>Aperam</li>
    <li>Totam</li>
    <li>Rem</li>
  </ul>
</navbar>

<nav>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <!-- float this left -->
    <li>Sunt</li>
    <li>Beatae Vita</li>
  </ul>
  Doleremquee laudantium otam Doloremque laudantium otam

  <ul class="nav-items">
    <!-- float this right-->
    <li>Arhieto</li>
    <li>Aperam</li>
    <li>Totam</li>
    <li>Rem</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This is my code https://jsfiddle.net/4zpmskro/

Answer (score 2):

So in order to make this work with the code you are using I tried to keep your use of `ul` consistent.

```
<nav>
  <ul class="title-area">
    <!-- float this left -->
    <li>Sunt</li>
    <li>Beatae Vita</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>Doleremquee laudantium otam Doloremque laudantium otam</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="nav-items">
    <!-- float this right-->
    <li>Arhieto</li>
    <li>Aperam</li>
    <li>Totam</li>
    <li>Rem</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Then in your CSS I added this

```
nav ul {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

This will add a right border to your `ul` elements and then remove the last one. I only applied this to the bottom `nav` but the same set up could be applied to the top navigation bar as well. Border is red but you can change it to any color. Here is an [updated version of your js.fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crazymatt/4zpmskro/5/) Hope that helps.